# WDIO V8 Selenium await isn't waiting for elements generated after page load

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, async-await, promise, wdio

I've a container $('#container'), which is there when the DOM is drawn.

This container is filled with inputs after the page has loaded due to an ajax request completing. However my await function seems to be firing as soon as the page has loaded and doesn't wait for any of the other requests to finish.

```
const container = await $('#container');
console.log(container) // = [container]
const inputs = await container.$$('input');
console.log(inputs) // = []
```

However, if I put an

```
const container = await $('#container');
console.log(container) // = [container]
await browser.pause(5000);
const inputs = await container.$$('input');
```

To make the script wait 5 seconds before, then the

```
console.log(inputs) // = [input, input, input, input....]
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong. From reading the documentation of WDIO V8, the whole point of the async style is to rely on promises, and not arbitrary browser.pause()'s as these can be unreliable.